# Description of the process of finding the name

Tags: c++

Help describe the process of finding the name x in the last line of the fragment:

```
struct S { static int x; void f(); };
int S::x;
int x;
void S::f() { x; // <-- }
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: `x;` doesn't do anything so far.

Comment: I want to understand the name lookup process of x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name lookup process for an unqualified name in the body of a class member function is described in [basic.lookup.unqual]/8. The following scopes are searched in order:

- The block in which the name is referenced, then the enclosing blocks within the same function
- The members of the class, then the members of base classes (if any)
- The members of the enclosing class or function, then of its base classes if any, then of its enclosing class or function, then of its base classes if any, and so on
- The enclosing namespace, then its enclosing namespace, and so on up to the global namespace

Thus, in this case, the body of `S::f()` is searched first to find a declaration of `x`; this fails, so a member of class `S` with name `x` is then looked for; this finds the static member `S::x`. The lookup process stops before considering the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure I understand your question, but if you would like to access the global variable `x` instead of the member `x` you can use the [`scope resolution operator`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-operator-in-c/) `::`

```
void S::f() {
  // Assign value of global variable to member x
  x = ::x;

  // Use the value of the member x
  int y = x;
}
```